# How to call native method wrapped by some dll non using DLLs wrapper?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, native

So I look at Reflector and see something like

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall), WrapperlessIcall]
public static extern blablabla();
```

That exists inside of some DLL I am looking at. I wonder how to call it from my code having that dll refrenced inside my but project not using that DLLs C# function wrapper directly?

Answer (score 0):

Typically MethodImplOptions.InternalCall refers to mscorlib which contains internal methods that we are not allowed to call directly (if you try you'll get an exception).

If this is not mscorlib and you're asking how to p/Invoke, check the [Platform Invoke Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468.aspx).